# Не происходит клик до движения мышью(mouse_event)

Tags: c#, winapi, мышь

Выполняю клик на точке вот такой вот функцией:

```
    public static void ClickToCoordinates(IntPtr hWnd, Point point, RECT mainRectangle)
    {
        Point absolutePoint = GetAbsolutePoint(point, mainRectangle);
        ShowWindow(hWnd);
        SetFocus(hWnd);
        Cursor.Position = absolutePoint;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)absolutePoint.X, (uint)absolutePoint.Y, 0, new UIntPtr(0));
    }
```

Зачастую срабатывает хорошо, но иногда мышь перемещается, а клика не происходит. Но(что самое странное для меня) он происходит, если двинуть реальной мышью хоть на пиксель. Отследить пошагово не могу, т.к. тогда не будет видно окна, в котором клик, в общем, затруднительно. При этом выполнение, как бы застывает, потому что если бы клик прошел впустую, то выполнение пошло бы дальше и его не происходило бы. Как это можно объяснить и исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй разделить на три события.

```
mouse_event(MOVE | ABSOLUTE, absolutePoint.X, absolutePoint.Y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); 
mouse_event(LEFT_DOWN, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); 
mouse_event(LEFT_UP, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
```

Попробуй разные виды задержки между событиями.

```
mouse_event(MOVE | ABSOLUTE, absolutePoint.X, absolutePoint.Y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); 
Thread.Sleep(200);
mouse_event(LEFT_DOWN, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); 
Thread.Sleep(100);
mouse_event(LEFT_UP, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: mouse_event(MOVE | ABSOLUTE, absolutePoint.X, absolutePoint.Y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); - эта инструкция не работает, почему-то кликает в левом верхнем углу.
Оставил как было, заменив только событие клика(разбив на две инструкции) - все такая же ситуация.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко Абсолютные координаты для функции mouse_event рассчитываются по формуле: абс-координаты-в-пикселях * 65536 / размер_экрана_в_пикселях. abs_x = abs_pixel_x * 65536 / desktop_width; abs_y = abs_pixel_y * 65536 / desktop_height.

Comment: А это как-то влияет на сам клик? Мышь перемещается корректно и сейчас.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко Не все программы корректно обрабатывают "слипшиеся" события, когда 3 события идут одним пачкой и/или в один момент времени.
Попробуй еще задержки (добавил в сам ответ).