# Как программно нажать кнопку в игре

Tags: python, c#

Я пишу бота для мморпг.
Как с помощью python или с# можно програмно нажать определенную кнопку?

Знаю, что это как-то делается при помощи внедрения кода в процесс игры (как например это делает cheat engine).

Буду благодарен если скинете ссылки на примеры/github

Comment: Есть такая штука pywinauto
https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

Можно при помощи неё, например

Comment: C# - NuGet пакет InputSimulator, но оно просто эмулирует нажатия на клаву/мышь. Окно должно быть на экране, никакого внедрения в процесс не происходит.

Comment: На счет C#. Некоторые игры не позволяют этого делать, но есть такая штука как DllImport и методы keybd_event, mouse_event, SendMessage и т.д. Примеры тут (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585442/Нажать-на-кнопку-в-стороннем-приложении-используя-winapi) и тут (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479533/Не-происходит-клик-до-движения-мышьюmouse-event)

Comment: InputSimulator не подходит, тк это симуляция нажатий на клавишу, а я говорю про, например нажатие мышкой на игровую кнопку ходьбы или удара